# Shortest way to add CSS rules with vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a library that I'm trying to keep it below 1KB. Which I'm already very close to my limits. I need to add a css rule to control show hide behaviour.

```
[hidden]{ display:none !important }
```

HTML page does not have any style tags. This will be only rule I need. I can only add it with pure JS. I **do not** want to change the style of an element with el.style.display = 'none'. I want to do it with an attribute.

So how can I add this, I found solutions that create a style element and set it's innerHTML and append it to head element. I'm hoping I can get an answer / a hack to maybe do it with less characters.

Comment: Create your stylesheet inside JS file then create `script` tag. InnerText the stylesheet and append child to `head`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the shortest I got, please make it shorter if you can.

```
const addCSS = s => document.head.appendChild(document.createElement("style")).innerHTML = s;

// Usage:
addCSS("[hidden]{ display:none !important }");
```

Comment: You can remove spaces inside the CSS rule: "[hidden]{display:none!important}" and around equals signs. (yeayea, I know;)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide an element with an attribute, simply use the attribute `hidden`.

**Example:**

```
<div hidden class="container"></div>
```

If you do not want to use `el.style.display = 'none'`, you could also use `cssText` to use your whole style in only 1 string.

**Example:**

```js
document.querySelector('.container').style.cssText = 'width: 100vw; height: 100vh; background: rebeccapurple;';
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Another option would be using the method [CSSStyleSheet.insertRule()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule).

> The CSSStyleSheet.insertRule() method inserts a new CSS rule into the
>   current style sheet, with some restrictions.

**Example:**

```js
const css = window.document.styleSheets[0];
css.insertRule(`
  .container {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: rebeccapurple;
  }
`, css.cssRules.length);
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: Nice hacks, didn't know about them. Not sure it exactly answers the OP though.