# How to set CSS class property in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, class, properties

I'm trying change CSS class property value. I'm using this soluction:

```
let pizzas = document.querySelectorAll('.pizza');
pizzas.forEach( pizzaElement => pizzaElement.style.display = 'none' );
```

Anyone has a solution without use iteration?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I change an element's class with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/how-can-i-change-an-elements-class-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use `classList` API with possibility to add, remove or toggle CSS classes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Comment: I'm trying change one property of this class, not add/remove classes

Answer (score 0):

```
let pizzas = document.querySelectorAll('.pizza');
 
pizzas.forEach( pizzaElement => pizzaElement.classList.add('d-none') );
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Markov88/mrfv914x/15/)

**EDIT:**
Please describe exactly where you want to use it. If you do not want to change the property of any event it is unnecessary to do with JS. You can overwrite css or add a new class ..

Comment: I'm looking for a solution without use iteration

Comment: You can add a new rule then, please check that - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56824866/shortest-way-to-add-css-rules-with-vanilla-js

Answer (score 0):

if your using pure **JavaScript** You can use this code:

```
let pizzas = document.querySelectorAll('.pizza');
pizzas[0].style.display = 'none';
pizzas[1].style.display = 'none';
pizzas[2].style.display = 'none';
```

or if you are using **JQuery** you can use this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('.pizza').css('display','none');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<DOCTYPE html>

  <head>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="pizza">Some Text</div>
    <div class="pizza">Some Other Text</div>
    <div class="pizza">Text</div>
  </body>

  </html>
```

Comment: I'm using pure javascript and looking for a solution without use iteration

Comment: @ChristianEduardo The solution is: make a class in your CSS file that implements your desired style. then use this JS code to implement it on your page:`elementName.classList.add("THE CLASS NAME")`